# Creating a ZigBee network

Tags: api, sensors, xbee, zigbee, texas-instruments

For a school project our client wants us to create a ZigBee network either using the Texas instruments cc2531 or a XBee. We've got a CC2531 with some sensors from Cleode. In their program, named cleobee, everything works fine. The connection is automatically made, and we don't have to do anything else than turn on the sensors for the connection to be made.

Now we want to use the CC2531 to connect with the sensors without using the Cleode program. Is there a simple way to set up a network? Is there an API we can use? We've found zTool in which we can monitor the usage of the cc2531, but we don't really know what else we can do with it.

Also, we would like to connect an Olimex mod-zigbee-pir sensor with it. Can we do this in the same manner as with the other sensors?

Is there any software available that let's us do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you donot want to use the Cleode program than you can implement the same thing yourself by making changes in the API provided by TI.

Ti has provided all the APIs and you can refer it in the Documents that comes along with Z-stack.

Also sample and Generic programs for zigbee networks are provided which you can modify it according to your requirement.